# Identify connected sheets usage in GCP billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

We're using connected sheets to trigger request on BigQuery.
We're trying to identify the cost of this usage on the billing account but there is only a BQ analysis service. Nothing identified in SKU as "connected sheets" for example.

Is there anyone who found a way to easily identify usage of connected sheets request on GCP ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to see queries run by a service account or a user. You can filter from Cloud Logging by email, and identify the `totalBytesBilled` and `totalBytesProcessed` to calculate the cost. In this case, Connected Sheets will be using either a service account or a user to run the queries, you can filter based on that.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks a lot for your answer, we will try to investigate your solution!